# <select> element value is blank even when the option is selected

Tags: javascript

My code:

```
function dispatchfile(rowData) {
    populatedept(function (optionsData) {
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.id = "survey-form";
        var elements = [
            {
                type: "div", // Change the type to "div"
                className: "wrapper-div", // Add class for styling
                label: "Send to",
                elements: [
                    { type: "select", label: "Select Department", id: "select_dept", options: [
                    { value: "", label: "Select Department" }, // Default option
                        ...optionsData.map(function (option) {
                            return { value: option, label: option };
                        }),
                    ] },
                    { type: "select", label: "Select Employee", id: "empno" }
                 ]
             }
        ];
        elements.forEach(function (element) {
            var wrapper;
            var label = document.createElement("label");
            label.className = "form-label";
            label.textContent = element.label;
            if (element.type === "div") {
                wrapper = document.createElement("div");
                wrapper.className = element.className;
                element.elements.forEach(function (el) {
                    var label = document.createElement("label");
                    label.className = "form-label";
                    label.textContent = el.label;

                    var input;
                    if (el.type === "select") {
                        input = document.createElement("select");
                        input.id = el.id;
                        input.className = "user-input";

                        if (el.options) {
                            el.options.forEach(function (option) {
                                var optionElement = document.createElement("option");
                                optionElement.value = option.value;
                                optionElement.text = option.label;
                                input.appendChild(optionElement);
                            });
                        }

                        if (el.id === "select_dept") {
                            input.onchange = function () {
                                getallemployees(input.value,rowData);
                            };
                        }
                     }
                     wrapper.appendChild(label);
                     wrapper.appendChild(input);
                     $(document).ready(function() {
                         $('#' + input.id).select2();
                     });
                });
                form.appendChild(label);
                form.appendChild(wrapper);
             }
        });
        document.getElementById("main_section").appendChild(form);
        if(rowData["sent_from_dept"] != null){
            document.getElementById("select_dept").value = rowData["sent_from_dept"];
            getallemployees(document.getElementById("select_dept").value,rowData);
        }
    });
}

function getallemployees(selectedDeptValue,rowData){
    var empno = document.getElementById("empno");

    if (selectedDeptValue !== "") {
        fetchOptionsFromServer(selectedDeptValue, function (empOptions) {
            empno.innerHTML = '';

            var defaultOption = document.createElement("option");
            defaultOption.value = "";
            defaultOption.text = "Select employee";
            empno.appendChild(defaultOption);

            empOptions.forEach(function (option) {
                var optionElement = document.createElement("option");
                    optionElement.value = option;
                    optionElement.text = option;
                    empno.appendChild(optionElement);
                });

                var val = ""
                if(rowData["sent_from"] != null){
                    Array.from(empno.options).forEach(function(option) {
                        if (option.value.includes(rowData["sent_from"])) {
                            val = option.value;
                        }
                    });
                    if(val != ""){
                        empno.value = val;
                        console.log(empno.value); //this prints the value
                    }
                 }
             });
         } else {
             empno.innerHTML = '';
         }
    }
}
```

The problem is inside `if(rowData["sent_from"] != null){....}`. The `empno.value` is set, but the text in the <select> element is empty, like this

[image: this]

I even tried logging the `empno.value` in the console, which shows correctly. Then why is the text of the selected value not showing inside the `empno` field, like how the value ACCOUNTS in the above element is showing. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please click [edit], then the `[<>]`  button and create a [mcve] with RELEVANT CODE and HTML using mock data